# External images from unsafe HTTPS source

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, https, jquery-templates

Setup info:

- ASP.NET web backend
- 99% jQuery based webpages, only thing ASP.NET is doing is to run the Index.html

Straight to the problem:

- A user perform a search
- The result is templated with jQuery templating
- The result contains data, and a URL-reference to an image.
- The image is placed on another server - secure/https - on the same domain.
- When jQuery is done templating the Chrome complains: `Failed to load resource`
- I have tried to request the image URL manually, and have found out the HTTPS certificate is **unsecure** and I need to tell Chrome that it's okay to continue using the unsafe certificate.

I can't figure out how to automatically bypass this unsafe certificate. The user shouldn't have to open each image and click "continue" in order to see the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule, you can't and shouldn't bypass an unsafe certificate.

If the user is in your own organization, you could require them to add this particular certificate to their exception list in their browser. This would make their browsers trust this one site and no others.

If this site is for external users, spend the money to get a proper SSL certificate. Having a self-signed certificate reflects badly on your organization.

Or go the simpler route and put the images on a non-SSL server.